# application default credentials for android project

Tags: android, environment-variables, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to access google sheets from an app that I am writing. I've been following the quickstart guide here: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/values but I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined pointing to a file defining the credentials.
```

EDIT:
I have created my credentials.json and downloaded it to my project's `app` directory as specified in the android quick start guide above.

I'm assuming that setting the environmental variable on my windows machine where the android emulator is running will not work for when this app gets installed on a real device.

This is the code that gets the credentials:

```
fun getValues(range: String) : String {
        val credentials = GoogleCredentials.getApplicationDefault().createScoped(Collections.singleton(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS))
        val requestInitializer = HttpCredentialsAdapter(credentials)
        val service = Sheets.Builder(
            NetHttpTransport(),
            GsonFactory.getDefaultInstance(),
            requestInitializer
        ).setApplicationName("FRCScout22").build()

        val result : ValueRange = service.spreadsheets().values().get(ID, range).execute();
        return result.toString()
    }
```

Is it possible to set an environmental variable on android? What is Google Compute Engine?

If anyone could clear this up for me that would be great!!

Comment: It seems the error was due to the credential file not being found. Are you using a Service Account? Or is it via OAuth? Basically, your goal here is to set up the right credentials for your app to be authenticated & to gain an access token to be used in accessing Google Sheet resources via the Sheet API. Perhaps review this official docs about [Google Workspace APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/android) & double check your project's setup.

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 sorry I forgot to mention in the OP but I have the credentials.json file in the projects "app" directory. I am trying to do this via OAuth. Should the file be in a different location?